# target attribute of a child element

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have the following list, and when the user clicks an li, I want to assign the value of the attribute src of img.tip in a variable. Any help with this please? Thanks!!

```
<ul class="list">
<li data-id="7" data-thumb="http://test.com/assets/pdc/thumbs/66.png" data-img="http://test.com/assets/pdc/img/66.png" data-country="Australia" data-company="Big Farm" data-app="Tea" data-brand="Big Farm" data-package="500" class="product air-500 cat7">
    <img class="tip" data-country="Australia" data-brand="Big Farm" src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif">
</li>
</ul>
```

for some reason this code picks up the data-thumb attribute in the clicked li element :S any know why?

```
$(".list li").on("click", function() {
    var src = $(this).children(".tip").prop("src");
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".list li").on("click", function() {
    var src = $(this).children(".tip").prop("src");
    // ...
});
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason that picks up the data-thumb attribute in the clicked li element, any idea why this might be?

Comment: @user1937021 It can't. It simply gets the full URL from your `src` attribute. You may also use `.attr("src")` instead of `.prop("src")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li onclick="var x = this.getElementsByName('img')[0].src">
   <img src="kittens.jpg" />
</li>
```

Comment: thanks, but can I not do with jquery, I need to it with jquery preferably

Comment: "cannot do with jquery. need to use jquery" Huh? jquery **IS** javascript, and my example is plain javascript.